# Curvas / Ondas em CSS

Tags: css, webdesign

É possível fazer, em puro css ou com alguma outra técnica esses efeitos ondulados (imagem anexo)? Eu não quero utilizar imagens para faze-los.

[image: ...]

Comment: Talvez você consiga esse efeito usando canvas, mas disso eu não entendo muito.

Comment: Talvez SVG, seja uma boa opção, observe [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27778980/2290538).

Comment: http://codepen.io --> busque por "wave", com animação (canvas, js...) fica bem mais legal.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fjSc/9/)

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202548/wavy-shape-with-css)

css

```css
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #e0efe3;
}
#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 340px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: -5px;
  top: 40px;
}
#wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #e0efe3;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wave"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma pergunta, você gostaria de trabalhar com os elementos `div`, `img` com um efeito de ondulação?

Ou somente uma linha com efeito de ondulação? Dá pra fazer um efeito assim com o elemento `<hr>`

Seletor `:after`, insere um conteúdo antes do elemento especificado;

Seletor `:before`, insere um conteúdo ápos o elemento especificado;

Pra deixar mais visual como estou montando essa linha "meio ondulada":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me aproveito das diagonais do conteúdo criado antes e depois do elemento `hr` para tentar criar um efeito de ondulação que não fica perfeito, mas razoável.

```css
.wave {
  border:0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-style: groove hidden hidden hidden;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  width: 57%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: 0px;
  top: 40px;
}

.wave:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 50%;
  border-style: hidden hidden groove hidden;
  border-color: #ff0000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0;
  top: 27px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="wave" />
```