# Slide com base arredondada

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeira vez que preciso fazer um slide desse tipo, veio em mente usar um slide normal com uma *div* sobrepondo a parte de baixo do slide, dando o efeito arredondado. Há outra maneira de fazer isso?

**EDIT:**

Deverá funcionar nos navegadores: IE, Firefox e Chrome;

Conteúdo ajustável à tela;

Não haverá barras de rolagem na página;

Também disponível para dispositivos móveis.

Comment: Maneiras há mil, mas a mais adequada depende de muitos outros fatores. Se o tamanho vai ser fixo, se vai se adequar a diferentes dispositivos, qual o público alvo (pra saber o quanto dá pra contar com recursos mais mondernos) etc. - Seria melhor se você clicasse em [edit] e desse o máximo de detalhes do projeto, senão fica meio aberta a pergunta. A propósito, se não quiser complicar demais, bastaria sobrepor uma imagem com CSS no slide normal. Sò precisa ver como é que vão funcionar as "orelhinhas" que indicam qual slide é o atual.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Curvas / Ondas em CSS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76335/3635)

Comment: Porque não simplesmente adicionar uma imagem à caixa do slider, está referir-se à de baixo certo?

Comment: BACCO, detalhes adicionados na pergunta.  GUILHERME,  vou testar essa opção. MIGUEL, não entendi hahaha